# Как передать массив byte из java в c++

Tags: java, c++, jni

В java объявлен метод

```
public native String stringFromJNI(byte[] b);
```

А на c++ объявлена функция

```
Java_theflipsiderebirth_testclintgame_1write_1in_1androidstudio_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, object obj, jbyte b[]){...}
```

Однако по адресу в переменной `b` лежит мусор. Почему?

Comment: Наверное, вам сперва стоит выделить место в неуправляемой памяти, скопировать туда ваш массив и передать функции указатель на эту память. Так как память, выделенная в куче динамическая и указатели на объекты могут измениться в процессе сжатия кучи.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому, что объявление функции некорректно. Утилита [javah](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) генерирует такое определение

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_MainActivity_stringFromJNI
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jbyteArray);
```

Обратите внимание, что `jbyteArray` - это не `byte[]`, это тип ссылки на массив байт.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jbyteArray b) {
    jsize size = env->GetArrayLength(b);
    jbyte* buffer = env->GetByteArrayElements(NULL);

    ...

    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(b, buffer, JNI_ABORT);
}
```